# openshift online: Error on StartContainer - ErrImagePull: "unauthorized: authentication required"

Tags: docker, openshift

I'm new to openshift and I have a showstopper:

On my Computer I created a Dockerimage called `restservice` and I successfully tested it:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 restservice
```

Then I created an app in Openshift-Online with the image:

```
oc new-app restservice
```

I can see the deployment-pod is starting and after the creating of the running pod is failing.

with

```
oc describe pod restservice-2-50n0h
```

I get the following Error:

```
...
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                    SubObjectPath           Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                    -------------           --------    ------      -------
  1m        1m      1   {default-scheduler }            Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned restservice-2-50n0h to ip-172-31-54-238.us-west-2.compute.internal
  41s       41s     1   {kubelet ip-172-31-54-238.us-west-2.compute.internal}   spec.containers{restservice}    Normal      Pulling     pulling image "restservice:latest"
  39s       39s     1   {kubelet ip-172-31-54-238.us-west-2.compute.internal}   spec.containers{restservice}    Warning     Failed      Failed to pull image "restservice:latest": unauthorized: authentication required
  39s       39s     1   {kubelet ip-172-31-54-238.us-west-2.compute.internal}                   Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "restservice" with ErrImagePull: "unauthorized: authentication required"

  55s   9s  2   {kubelet ip-172-31-54-238.us-west-2.compute.internal}   Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "SetupNetwork" for "restservice-2-50n0h_wgbeckmann" with SetupNetworkError: "Failed to setup network for pod \"restservice-2-50n0h_wgbeckmann(06f892b4-7568-11e7-914e-0a69cdf75e6f)\" using network plugins \"cni\": CNI request failed with status 400: 'Failed to execute iptables-restore: exit status 1 (iptables-restore: line 3 failed\n)\n'; Skipping pod"
```

I have no Idea what Authentication is needet.

Comment: Did you go to the About page top right under question mark drop down menu, get the details of the internal registry in OpenShift, login to that registry and push your docker image from your local computer into OpenShift? OpenShift cannot see images you build on your local computer, they need to be pushed up to a image registry which it can pull them down from.

Comment: The hostname of the registry if not shown in that version of web console, would for your environment likely be ``registry.starter-us-west-2.openshift.com`` if that is the starter tier.

Comment: PERFECT! after pushing it to the Register it works.
Thanks!

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Maybe you'd like to turn those comments into an answer so the OP can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

The missing step is to pusch the Image to openshift online.

So these are the Steps:

- Build a Image on the local Computer

  `docker build -t restservice .`
- Tag it with registry/username/image-name

  `docker tag restservice registry.starter-us-west2.openshift.com/myusername/myrestservice`
- Get your Secret for the Login into the Openshift Registry

  `oc whoami -t
  sr3grwkegr3kjrk42k2jrg34kb5k43g5k4jg53` (sr3... is the output)
- Log into Openshift Registry

  `docker login -u name@mail.com -p sr3grwkegr3kjrk42k2jrg34kb5k43g5k4jg53 https://registry.starter-us-west-2.openshift.com`
- Push the Image to the Registry

  `docker push registry.starter-us-west-2.openshift.com/myusername/myrestservice`
- Create the new App with the Image

  `oc new-app myrestservice`

Thats all ....